# how to retrieve custom field at root directory for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i have create a redir.php and placed in the home directory of wordpress to do the redirect. I want to pass in the post id and then retrieve a custom field value of the post and feed into header('location:'.$url);

www.mysite.com/redir.php?id=30
in redir.php will retrieve post id=30 custom field value and pass it into $url.

this is what I have, but it's not working. It gives me "Parse error: parse error in \redir.php on line 5".

it looks like wordpress environment is not being loaded.

```
 <?php

    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
      $id = $_GET['id'];
  $url= get_field('deal_http_link',post->$id);
    header('Location:'.$url);
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your script has multiple issues:

- There is whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag, so the redirect wouldn't work because the headers will have already been sent. Instead, `<?php` should be the very first thing in the file.
- `post->$id` is invalid syntax. You probably meant the `$id` variable which you defined in the preceding line.
- To retrieve the value of a custom field, use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), not get_field().

Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = get_post_meta($id, 'deal_http_link', true);
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit();
```

Comment: thanks.  I was able passing in the id correctly by echo $id.  However, it returns a blank page.  I tried to echo out the $url but nothing came out.  I checked the database, wp_postmeta and the meta_key is "deal_http_link" and post_id i used to check is "935". thanks

Comment: Somehow make me think that wordpress is not being fully loaded, therefore, when use "get_post_meta", it doesn't return anything.  this "redir.php" is being called at the home directory.  Like this "http://localhost/redir.php?id=935"   Thanks

Comment: What *does* get_post_meta() return? False/NULL/an empty string? Also, are you sure the post in question actually has the required custom field.

Comment: get_post_meta() returned NULL.  I went into mysql table and looked the ost_meta and confirmed that 'deal_http_link" exists and it has a url value next to the post_id.

Comment: got it working!   Thanks very much :)  how do I put a delay before the jump to display some message with html code?   thanks

Comment: got it, just use 'refresh' instead of location :)

Comment: You could try a [JavaScript redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745622/529673) with setTimeout.