# How to use link instead of alert?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
function destroy()
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        alert("User will be deleted")
    }

    else {

    }

}
```

But I don't want to show alert message, I want the user to be redirected by my own link.
What should I write instead of `alert` to do that ?

Comment: Did you search before asking this question? Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/javascript-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    window.location = 'your_link_here';
}
```