# PHP : How to use alert() before header('location:http://domain.com');

Tags: php, javascript

How to use `alert()` before `header('location:http://domain.com');` so that alert work.
the problem is that php code is powerful and ignore alert()

Comment: No the php code is not powerful .... it runs on the server .. so the page redirects before js has a chance to even see the alert :)

Comment: Which is it, displaying a message or redirecting? You can't do both at once.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this?

```
alert('After this goes away, I will be redirected via JavaScript');
window.location = "http://domain.com";
```

Ref.  [How do I redirect with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/javascript-redirect)

Comment: Thanks for trying to actually help the poor fellow :)

Comment: Hey we've all been there ;)

Answer (score 1):

To use Javascript like alert() you have to have a loaded web page. You can do the header() function then within the next request that is probably called after the alert.