# Load different html page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load different html page at button click
Here is my main page code

```
<body>

<div id="header">    
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu1" name="radio"><label for="navmenu1">Home</label>
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu2" name="radio"><label for="navmenu2">Contact</label>
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu3" name="radio"><label for="navmenu3">Resume</label>
</div>

</div><!--head-->

<div id="content-area">
<div id="content"></div>    
</div>

<div id="footer-row">
  <footer>
     <div id="footer-row-1">
        <ul id="footer">
            <li>&copy 2013 by Han Chang</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-row-2">        
    </div>
</footer>
</div>

</body>
```

my `home.js` code as below

```
$(function () {
$("#radio").buttonset();   
$("#radio :radio").click(function (e) {
    var $val = $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).val();
    alert($val);
});
```

I want to know which button I choose, then load its html page.
How can I do this ?  Thank you

Comment: Why you want to load different HTML page? It seems like you just want to load different information in content area. Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mutant this sounds like a dynamic page loading that might be used with AJAX queries, no?

Comment: Hi Mutant,  you are right, sorry!! I wanna load dynamic page

Comment: I want the content area shows different content when I click buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.location. Assuming the input/anchor/button has the context to create the desired url.

```
window.location = 'http://your.url.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onclick` event for each button to call a js function.

```
<input type="radio" id="navmenu1" name="radio" onclick="someFunction()"><label for="navmenu1">Home</label>
```

You could send in a string or something to that function to determine which button was clicked. The function that you call can redirect to a different html page by using `window.location`

Comment: **onclick event for each button** - this is bad advice..`onclick`'s better sibling is jQuery's `on`. what if he has many buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the value, you can add the logic, for example:

```
if (val === "Option 1") {
    // Action here
}
```

It sounds like you want to change some content on the page, which is a simple JQuery function:

```
$("body").replaceWith(//HTML here);
```

More info on that function: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

So the complete example would be something like:

```
if (val === "Option 1") {
    $("body).replaceWith("<body><h2>Option 1</h2></body>");
}
```

or whatever you fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can load new HTML into your page using AJAX. You could have a set page of HTML and load it into your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery template plugin or get html by jquery and httphandler

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the radio button, you need to have a `value` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/TpmTt/

then, you can check and redirect the user using [window.location, window.navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/javascript-redirect)