# how to check the status of css through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript file that validates if the text-box is filled out or not.
I want to make it that if all the text-boxes are all filled out correctly, it should go on to the next page or what ever the case is. (In my case just to display an alert message box.)   I would appreciate any answer as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" onSubmit="return validate()" method="post">
    <p>
        <label class="tittle">Name:</label>
        <span>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"
                   placeholder="First Name" class="info"
                   size="25" maxlength="25" 
                   onBlur="return validateFirstName()">
            <label class="fillerror" id="fillFirst">
                 First name is required
        </label>
        </span>

        <span>
            <input type="text" name="lastname"
                   placeholder="Last Name" class="info"
                   size="25" maxlength="25"
                   onBlur="return validateLastName()">
            <label class="fillerror" id="fillLast">
                 Last name is required
        </label>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="register"
               value="Register" class="register"
               onClick="return validateFirstName(),
               validateLastName(), allValidated();">
    </p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function xValidate(inbox, fill)
{
    inbox.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 0, 0, .1)";
    inbox.style.borderLeft="3px solid red";
    fill.style.display="block";
}
function yValidate(inbox, fill)
{
    inbox.style.backgroundColor="white";
    inbox.style.borderLeft="3px solid rgb(169, 184, 1)";
    fill.style.display="none";
}


function validateFirstName()
{   
    var frstnm = document.forms["form"] ["firstname"].value;

    var inbox = document.forms["form"] ["firstname"];
    var firstname = document.getElementById("fillFirst");

    if (frstnm==null || frstnm=="" || frstnm==" ")
    {
        xValidate(inbox, firstname);
    }
    else
    {
        yValidate(inbox, firstname);
    }
}   

function validateLastName()
{
    var lstnm = document.forms["form"] ["lastname"].value;

    var inbox = document.forms ["form"] ["lastname"];
    var lastname = document.getElementById("fillLast");

    if (lstnm==null || lstnm=="" || lstnm==" ")
    {
        xValidate(inbox, lastname);
    }
    else
    {
        yValidate(inbox, lastname);
    }
```

}

This is **the** function I need help on, all other code here was just for information to understand this last statement:

```
function allValidated()
{

    var allrGood = document.getElementsByClassName("fillerror");

    if (allrGood.style.display="none" == true)
    {
        alert("They're all good");
    }
    else if (allrGood.style.display="block" == true)
    {
        alert("Something is displayed 'block'");
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work with an 'if' statement, then maybe it would work with a 'for' or 'while' statement (looping statement) then please show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would really suggest that you start using jQuery. It'll make things quite easy.

Here is a pure JS solution though -

1. First assign a particular class to all the controls that need to be
   validated.
2. On the onchange event of the controls, if the controls are valid,
   add a certain class say - `ctrlValid` , else add another class -
   `ctrlInvalid`.
3. Then on the click of the button, get all elements by the class name
   `ctrlInvalid`
4. Check if the length is 0, if it is - redirect, else show message.

If you continue to use your solution then -

```
var blIsFormValid = true;
for(var i =0; i < allrGood.length; ++i)
{
   if(allrGood[i].style.display != 'none')
   {
       blIsFormValid = false;
       break;
   }
}
if(blIsFormValid)
{
   // Redirect check - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745622/903324
   window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
}
else 
{
   // Show message...
}
```

Comment: It is a great answer, but how would I do the 2nd if statement?   if(blIsFormValid)
{
   // Redirect
}

Comment: @user2356557, updated the answer again.. The point of the for loop is that we are getting all the `fillerror` divs, and checking if they are displayed. If even one of them is displayed that means there is an error.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally worked!! Couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an *array* of elemets, not just one element. So `allrGood.style` doesn't quite make sense.

Also, `allrGood.style.display="none"` assigns `"none"` to `allrGood.style.display` instead of comparing them. Remember to use `==` for a loose comparison or `===` for a strict comparison.

Using jQuery you can iterate through each label of class `fillerror` and check to see if it's visible, like so:

```
function areTheyAllValidated() {
    var valid = true;
    $('label.fillerror').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(element).is(":visible"))
            valid = false;
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pop a class or ID on your alert control so you can style that sucka.

Something like below should get you in a decent direction. With another bell and whistle for sags.

```
'SuperCool': function() {
   var sName = document.getElementById('ip1').value;
   Alert.SuperCool( "Thank you "+sName+". Could be expanded to do something a little more clever" );
 }
```

*Example alert styling.*

```
.SuperCool {
   background: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}
```