# Redirecting a page if not redirected

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, error-handling, header

I have a php page in which I have number of queries, in the end I redirect the page using `header()`,sometimes if an error occurs on a query it produce Error and the redirection doesn't work.
I want to do something like `Please click here if it is not redirected`, is there any way to do that, I know I have to use an anchor tag in echo, I am thinking about the logic here
Any help in this regard

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Add `@ob_start();` top of the page

Comment: Strange question... why are you not asking how to force the redirect with `header()` to work irrespective of errors?

Comment: @eggyal I meant the same

Comment: @MichaelRushton code is just simple queryies and a header in the end, I am afraid that wouldn't help you

Comment: If the redirection isn't working because of some error then your code is poorly written. Showing us the code will allow us to explain how to fix it.

Comment: @KrishR how ob_start() will , it will only help me to clear the output on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ob_start();` in top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do so, just print "bla bla redirect in 10 seconds" then start a counter with java script, after finishing counter just redirect. Here is an example;

[How do I redirect with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/javascript-redirect)