# Javascript code redirect to a division on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

Allright this might be a general question but i wasn't able to find an answer to it.

I want the browser to move to another division(part) of the page once a user has clicked a specific button.How can this be achieved.

Comment: How were you not able to find a solution to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/javascript-redirect

Comment: Keep calm and Google.

Comment: You didn't get the question. I want the user to be able to redirect to another part of the page not to another page. Please take your negative back

Comment: @user3274745 Your question and your description of question didn't match. Please change your question title.

Comment: @user3274745 Well, in that case, Amit's solution should work.

Comment: I just changed the title . And yes Amit's solution worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<a href="#idOfAnotherPart">Click Here</a>` will move the page to the div or some other element whose id is `idOfAnotherPart`

Comment: 7 mins left for it ? What is it ?

Comment: There's a time after which you can accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks mates, didn't know it