# Javascript Code to go back to main page not previously browsed Page

Tags: javascript

How to get back to main page not on to the  previously browsed page.I have used javascript link  but it is returning previously browsed page.Can any one tell me how to go back to main page of any defined category like If I am browsing for any product we have main then category and then sub category so how to navigate from sub category to main using hyperlink coded in javascript.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use window's property object **location** and its attribute *origin*:

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin
```

Using this code on this page will relocate you to https://stackoverflow.com/, and this will also keep a port number if you have any specific defined, like http://localhost:8888/ in your development environment.