# on success of jquery validation the page not redirect on specific location

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, redirect

In my coding I am doing jQuery validation which is going successful but when it come to redirect page its not redirecting on given url. when i checked this using firebug it shows every correct field and also the html(given url). i dont know how to redirect the page.

on success i just want to open my admin_login/login page and if validation failed it goes on admin_login/index page.

```
 <?php include('assets/header.php'); ?> 

<div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Admin Login</h1>
    <?if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
    <p class='flashMsg flashError'> 
        <?= $this->session->flashdata('flashError') ?> </p>
    <?endif?>
    <!-- new line inserted -->
    <form method="post" name="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8"   class="login" id="form" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <!--<label for="admin">Admin</label>
                <input type="text" name="admin" class="form-control" id="admin" value=""  placeholder="admin name" />-->
                Admin Name: <input type="text" name="admin" id="admin" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('admin'); ?>"  placeholder="admin name" >
                <?php echo form_error("admin"); ?>
                <p id='p1'></p>
                <br>
                <!--  <label for="password">password</label>
                 <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value=""  placeholder="password" required/>
                -->
                Admin Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value=""  placeholder="password" >
                <?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
                <p id='p2'></p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </form> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var admin = $("#admin").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
            // Checking for blank fields.
            if (admin == '')
            {
                $('div.error').html("Please Fill Admin Required Fields");
            } else if (password == '')
            {
                $('div.error').html("Please Fill Password Required Fields");
            } else
            {//alert('hello world');
                // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login",
                    data: {"admin": admin, "password": password},
                    dataType: "json"

                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.error != "")
                    {
                        //alert('hello if');
                        $('div.error').html(data.error);
                    } else
                    {

                       // alert('hello else');
                        window.location.href="admin_view";
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<?php include('assets/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: hey you can alert in else part like alert('hello else');?

Comment: I guess you are using ajax in a wrong concept. If you need to validate and redirect then send the form and use redirect on PHP side. You still can use javascript for validation before sending. But if you don't know how to redirect on javascript read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745622/2406912

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @devidas Kadam. there is no any error

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 here full path like this 

window.location.assign("http://localhost/ss.php");
```

or

```
window.location.assign("<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login");
```

Comment: where to add this path?

Comment: window.location.href="admin_view"; replace this one into above code

Comment: add exit window.location.assign("<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login");     exit();

Comment: or try this for testing purpose window.location.replace("<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login");  if you use replace i cant go back to previous page .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110477/discussion-between-jothi-and-dinesh-gawande).

Comment: ajax result is success ?  or not ?

Comment: // alert('hello else'); uncomment this one and know ajax is success or not

Comment: //alert('hello if');  uncomment this one in if condition and know ajax is success or not

Comment: show your controller and model code .may be problem is there

Comment: have u check this/

Answer (score 0):

You will get the response in success function.

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login",
                data: {"admin": admin, "password": password},
                dataType: "json"
                success : function (data) {
                // alert('hello else');
                    window.location.href="<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login";
                },
                error: function() {
                     $('div.error').html("An error occurred");
                }

            });
```

Comment: @DineshGawande u need to debug the code, for that u store the whole url in one variable and display in alert box.

Comment: check if you are able to alert in success function. If not, then there is problem in your controller. Will have to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

try using full URL

```
window.location.href="<?php base_url() ?>index.php/admin_login/login";
```