# how to move to another page after displaying JavaScript alert

Tags: php

How can I move to another page after displaying the JavaScript alert. Thank you, :D
What's the next code for this to go to another page?

```
if(isset ($_POST['reply'])){

    echo "<script>alert('Login to continue.')</script>";

}
```

Comment: header('Location: another_page.php');

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript

Comment: @DharaParmar You can't reissue a header after you've printed to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for this

```
echo "<script>alert('Update Not Successfully');document.location='pagename.php'</script>";
```

do not forget to write script at start and end point in echo.

Comment: Thanks man. it worked! :D I'm almost done with my blog, my project in school. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **javascript** below way:

```
window.location = "http://www.domain.com";
```

Also you can try with PHP code:

```
header('Location: targetPage.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use JavaScript `confirm` and `window.location` both for it.

```
var r = confirm("Login to continue.");
if (r == true)
{
    window.location = "http://www.domain.com/agreed.html";
}
else
{
    window.location = "http://www.domain.com/cancelled.html";
}
```