# Alert box pops up - redirect on click "OK"

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to redirect users as and when click "OK" in the alert box. Any hints will be appreciated

```
if( $num_rows == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
    echo "No results!";
} else {
    $message = "Information already sent";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114003/how-to-move-to-another-page-after-displaying-javascript-alert/37114208#37114208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert('$message');
   document.location.href='your url';
</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` to redirect to any page in javascript, so that it will be redirected to test.php after use click OK in alertbox:

```
if( $num_rows == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
    echo "No results!";
} else {
    $message = "Information already sent";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');window.location.href='test.php';</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script>alert('Update Not Successfully');document.location='pagename.php'</script>";
```

Comment: It's a code-only answer, but it definitely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`window.location.replace(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) is better, than `window.location.href = url`, because is disallows user to go back at this page using button "previous page in history" in browser.

It does a real redirect instead of just going to the next url:

```
if( $num_rows == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
    echo "No results!";
} else {
    $message = "Information already sent";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); window.location.replace('test.php'); </script>";
}
```