# how do I automatically get page to change

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would a javascript script be so my browser automatically redirects to the next page example being.

wwww.page.com/1

www.page.com/2

www.page.com/3

and so on so on, changing every 10 seconds.

I would want to code be something I can just input in to my browser, I don't actually want it on a webpage

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

We can user `window.location` with in `setTimeout` function. Here I am giving an example code.

in `www.page.com/1` write

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.page.com/2" }, 10000);
```

in `www.page.com/2`

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.page.com/3" }, 10000);
```

and so on.
You can run the JavaScript code in browser console also, if you don't want to run in browser only.
`SetTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.