# Redirect traffic based on "?ref=XXX" at end o URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect

Incredibly, I've been unable to find any JS code for this scenario:

If people come to `http://example.com` I don't need anything to happen.

But if they come in as `http://example.com/?ref=producthunt`, we need to redirect them to another page, like `http://example.com/custom-landing.html`.

So sorry for the vague question but I've been Googling for hours now and no luck.

Comment: That would be a combination of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript).

Comment: you can use window.location.search to get the parameter

Answer (score -1):

use this function with the parameters matters

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Code Source: first answer here [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

and than create your link to redirect, and finally redirect usingo window.location = 'tour-url';

Comment: Plagiarism is lame. Shame. Just flag as a duplicate next time or provide a link in a comment.