# Input website into text field, click GO and person is taken to the website from my website

Tags: html, redirect

I need a simple html code so that a visitor to my website can type in a textfield what website they would like to visit next and click GO and they are taken there.

I can't seem to find how to do this anywhere.  Can't even find any websites that have a similar code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation that will set it based on the text field value. I would suggest putting in validation and much more.

```js
function goToUrl(form){
  window.location = form.url.value
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="goToUrl(this)">
  <input type="text" id="url" />
  <button type="submit">Go to URL</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not really good at coding anything but HTML.  Can you tell me what this kind of code might be called so I can look around and maybe find a better version of the script?  I've searched around but can't find it since I don't even know what its called.

Comment: the function is JavaScript which is the interaction layer for HTML that allows programmatic actions based on events.