# Laravel Redirect to Previous after login

Tags: jquery, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

Hi I am using the laravel authentication system which is out of the box but I want a behavior in which the user could redirect to his last page after login with user data. For logged in I using bootstrap validator

My login code in js file

```
    function do_login() {
                frm_name = 'userlogin';
                email = $('#userlogin input[id=email]').val();
                password = $('#userlogin input[id=password]').val();
                _token = $('#userlogin input[id=_token]').val();

                if (email == '' || password == '') {
                    $('#flashMessage').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                    $('#flashMessage').html('Please specify Email and Password');
                } else {
                    var param = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&_token=' + _token;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype: "json",
                        url: "/auth/login",
                        data: param,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status == 0) {
                                $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
                                window.location.href = '/';
                            }
                            if (data.status == 1) {
                                $('#flashMessage').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                                $('#flashMessage').html(data.message);
                            } else {
                                onError(data.Error, '#' + frm_name);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

    $(document).ready({
    $('#login').click(function () {
            do_login();
        });
});
```

So how can I managed the user could redirect to his last page after login using js. Thanks

Comment: `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` ?

Comment: do you want to redirect to a page which user enters in the url after login but redirect to login page if he is not yet authenticated?

Comment: @rohitshah now user is on search page and he wants to login.  user use his Auth and logged in now after logged in he redirect to search page

Comment: @rohitshah is it possible to redirect to search using js

Comment: following SO may have your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript

Comment: you can do that bt you'll have to pass the search parameter in the query string and use window.location after login success

Answer (score 1):

```
return  redirect::route('route_name')->with('msg_name', 'Message');
```

you can use the following to redirect back

```
use Redirect;
```

Comment: this is d way one can redirect to other page  for example on click of login button u can call it in following way n in href give link for your routes of that view page

Comment: <script>
// onclick event is assigned to the #button element.
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
};
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
return Redirect::back();
```

but before this you must add:

```
use Redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `http referrer` in built php or `return redirect()->back();` or `Redirect::back();`