# How to find URL subpath?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

I dont have any background in ASP.

So I need to access page 1, 2 and so on from the following link address http://www.itftennis.com/beachtennis/rankings/rankings-full-lists/men.aspx

I tried to use **/men.aspx?page=2** and nothing happened. Also, when I copied the link address from button of page 2 I get this **javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$ContentContainerCentre$BaselineContainerCentre$playerrankings_6$grdBeachTennisRankings','Page$2')**

The expected solution is **/men.aspx?page=n** or similar.

Is there any way to find URL path for each page from above link address?

Comment: men.aspx is already a page? what do you mean accessing page? Is there is any for query string in code behind?

Comment: @Imad I mean accessing subpath from [link] (http://www.itftennis.com/beachtennis/rankings/rankings-full-lists/men.aspx). Yes, there is a query string in code behind.

Comment: What's your expected output and current one? Nothing happen after putting page=2 means?

Comment: This page using pagination based on `VIEWSTATE`, `VIEWSTATE`using HTTP POST method. So for you question, there have no way. but you can simulator the HTTP POST to change page to 2.

Comment: Expected output should be http://www.itftennis.com/beachtennis/rankings/rankings-full-lists/men.aspx?page=2. however, it is not working. But, if I use the browser and click on button 2, the webpage will be refresh and bring the new data. The goal is to obtain the url for page 2. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @JohanShen I gonna try to use HTTP POST

Comment: @hbbz040 did you post these data? if you using `WebHttpRequest`, you need post data named '__EVENTTARGET', '__EVENTARGUMENT', '__VIEWSTATE' and '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' etc. they are in page html code, you need got them and post them to request other page.

Comment: Posted you request code better. then we can know how way do you request the page.

Comment: @JohanShen ok... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have tagged javascript. In JS, you can use

```js
window.location('link to your successive pages')
```

or

```js
window.location.href('link to your successive pages')
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript) answer for more clarification. Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to redirect the browser, no.