# Page Redirection if input is

Tags: javascript, html

I want a program to redirect a person to a site if he clicks the submit button in a form only if the text input is 12345 and redirect to another page of input is 56789 using Javascript

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some idea from the below code:

```js
function validate() {
 var digits = document.frm.digits1.value;
 if(digits == '12345')
 {
  location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  
 }
 else if (digits == '56789')
 {
  location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
 }
 else
 {
  alert('digits are wrong');
 }
 
 return false;
 
}
```

```html
<form name="frm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" >
<input type="text" name="digits1" id="digits1"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the code below:

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="#">
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if (text=="12345"){
        alert("Redirecting to: http://www.your.1st.url.com");
        document.location = "http://www.your.1st.url.com";
    } else if (text=="56789"){
        alert("Redirecting to: http://www.your.2nd.url.com");
        document.location = "http://www.your.2nd.url.com";
    }
}
```

Sources:

- [How do I redirect with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)
- [onsubmit function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit)

Comment: You are very welcome. Since it helped you can tick my answer as accepted and give it an upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following idea or similar.

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('myinput').value == '56789')
        document.getElementById('myform').action = 'anotherpage.html';
};
```