# How do I send a variable in the URL from a text input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, url, post

Using javascript, I'm trying to do the following. I'll boil this down into it's simplest version.

I'd like to pass a variable from a text field to a URL, and have the URL be visited when the form is submitted.

1. user enters a number into a text input field "123"
2. user clicks the submit button
3. Browser redirects to http://url.com/?myVariable=123 on click

The other question did not solve my problem because it didn't send a user-inputted variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Make the url string then redirect like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)!

Comment: You don't even need JS to achieve that, it is the standard behavior for forms using GET method. Good reading http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Interpretation

You want to redirect the user to

> https://www.example.com/?myVariable=whatevertheusertyped

### Solution

- If you give the field an id attribute, it's value is accessible via Javascript, i.e. `document.getElementById('id').value` will give you the value of `id` (where `id` can be whatever you want as the id).
- There is a Javascript variable `window.location.href` that, when changed, changes the URL of the page to what it was changed to.

**Thus**:

```html
<input type="text" id="test"><br><br>
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com?myVariable='+document.getElementById('test').value">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. You explained the syntax simply and brilliantly.

Comment: You're very welcome! If you found this useful, don't forget to mark as the accepted answer :D

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<form onSubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
    Enter name: <input id="myti" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        window.location.href = currentUrl+"?"+ document.getElementById("myti").value;
    }
</script>
```