# Issue Redirecting in php

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have a form that works (input data is transferred to Mysql database and redirects back to index.php) in my XAMP local sever but when I copy the files and code to my online hosting my data is uploaded to the database but the program is failing to redirect. Please have a look at my redirect code and let me know of any possible solutions.

```
// Insert
public function insert($query) {
    $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    //Validate Insert
    if($insert_row) {
        header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
        exit();
    } else {
        die ('Error : ('.$this->link->error.') '.$this->link->error);
    }
}
```

* This is just my insert function, with a redirect if insert is successful.

Comment: Is insert actually successful?

Comment: Like I said this functions works great in XAMP. I am new to this.

Comment: The database query works in XAMP, but you don't know if it works online?

Comment: I am running the exact same code online as in XAMP and getting different results. I think this is route cause because the rest of it is working as intended... uploading inputted data to the database the last step is to be redirected back to index.php

Comment: Then there is something different online. You need to check your error logs.

Comment: After my input query I run this... $insert_row = $db->insert($query); which I guess refers to the function I'm struggling with.

Comment: Sorry. How do I check error logs?

Comment: You could echo out a javascript redirect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript - does that work?

Comment: Thanks Usman Shahid. That work wonderfully!! Do you know why my php redirect failed though?

Comment: can you turn off error reporting `error_reporting(0);` and try again, i think there is something echoing before this redirect statement.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));`.

Make sure that you are not echoing out any HTML, or any other sort of text at all, before that statement is reached. Otherwise, your redirect will fail.