# Ajax request doesn't redirect to view in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security for the application. We are using spring form tags to request rest calls in the application. For a particular purpose, i am using ajax calls from the jsp. It calls the controller method successfully and does processing, but, the controller method doesn't land to a view  for some reason. I am not getting any error or anything in logs.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createRunOne/saveRun", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String saveRun(@RequestBody Run run, Model model){

    try{
        this.runService.saveRun(run);

    } catch (Exception ex){
            model.addAttribute(ERROR, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/run/list";
}
```

javascript function written in jsp:

```
function saveRun() {

                var run = {
                    runName: $('#name').val(),
                    description: $('#description').val(),
                    justification: $('#justification').val(),
                    scheduledTime: new Date($('#scheduledTime').val()),
                    fromReceiptDate: new Date($('#fromdatepicker').val()),
                    toReceiptDate: new Date($('#todatepicker').val()),
                    sourceKeyString: $('#segmentSelect').val().toString(),
                    selectedBlocks: $('#blockList').val().toString(),
                    compareFilter: $('#filtercase').val(),
                    productsSelected: selectedList.toString()
                };

                headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                headers['dataType'] = 'json'

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "createRunOne/saveRun",
                data: JSON.stringify(run),
                headers: headers,
                responseType: "application/json",

                success: function(response, data){

                    if(data=='success'){

                        }
                },
                error: function (xhr,  textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to redirect from AJAX request. You can return url to which you want to redirect and then redirect from frontend

Comment: what do you mean? this is what spring controller does.

Comment: You are using AJAX hence you need to redirect on the client.... What currently happens is that the 302 is handled by the browser and the result in the AJAX call is the HTML (or whatever you are redirecting) too. You should use that to re-render your page. Or instead of doing it like this, return a URL and redirect in your AJAX success function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect by this way in ajax call.

Better you return one success or failure flag and in the ajax success function do below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createRunOne/saveRun", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String saveRun(@RequestBody Run run, Model model){

    try{
        this.runService.saveRun(run);

    } catch (Exception ex){
            model.addAttribute(ERROR, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}
```

In view page use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript) to redirect :

```
success: function(response, data){
      if(data=='success'){
           window.location.replace('<redirect url>');
      }
},
```