# How do i make document.location.href behave like a simple link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

I have a select item with bunch of cities on my website. When the visitor selects some city this happens:

```
$("#city-selector").change(function() {
    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
    if (url) { // require a URL
        document.location.href = url; // redirect
    }
});
```

Each option inside the select has a `value` parameter that contains subdomain url in it.
The problem is `document.location.href` doesn't behave like a simple link. It clears visitor id and it looks like the visitor doesn't have a referer and came to the new subdomain out of nowhere. Is there a problem with functions I use or should I dig into crossdomain sessions/cookies? How do I make it behave properly?

Comment: Well, why not include the **visitor id** in the url or in the `value` attribute?

Comment: look at `https://stackoverflow.com/a/40233610/6309457`

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href`. This is similar when clicking a link

```
window.location.href = url;
```